# What is the best way to send and recieve text messages from my Ubuntu computer?

Tags: sms

Ideally, I'd like to use my normal cell phone number, but if that doesn't work, I'd like to be able to have some other line for texting and be able to do it from the computer.

Comment: My recommendation would be to use Google Voice. http://voice.google.com

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're asking how to send SMS messages or a recommendation for common messaging apps for your Ubuntu computer. To my knowledge, you can't use your computer to send SMS messages from your cell phone number.

If you have Google Voice service, you will be able to send SMS messages (and make phone calls) from that Google Voice number from Google Hangouts or GMail in your browser, which I do all the time.

If you're asking about messaging apps, you can use web.whatsapp in Google Chrome on Ubuntu, and you can also download Viber as an application in Ubuntu. I believe Viber can also make calls and send SMS messages, but I don't use that functionality and can't be certain.